# Formatting Currency Correctly for two UITextFields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, currency, nsnumberformatter

I have two UITextFields in my app and the app has to do with currency. I am attempting to have it formatted correctly with the $ at the beginning and the decimal where it should. Like I said. I have been unable to find a noob answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats happening here is you're adding an observer that tells us when the user is finished editing. Once that happens our `formatCurrency` method does the work of updating the look of the textfield. The changes take full affect once the number field resigns its first responder status.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(formatCurrency)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                               object:self.numberField];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.numberField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)formatCurrency {
    NSString *currentValue = self.numberField.text;
    long long cur = [currentValue longLongValue];
    NSNumber *curNum = @(cur);
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    self.numberField.text = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:curNum
                                          numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
}
```

Comment: I don't know, where do you want to see formatted numbers with currency symbols?

Comment: in my uitextfields. where u enter the bill total. Once the bill total is entered, i want the number that u entered to be in the correct format.

Comment: NSNumber newOutput = [formatter numberFromString:textFieldinputVariable]; [textfield setText:[newOutput stringFromNumber]];//I haven't tested this but this is the gist of how it works.

Comment: i am pretty sure that i am doing it wrong. i am a new ios developer so it can be tough at times. it is really late where i live so i will be going to sleep. if u dont mind, can u add me on skype at antomir0121, and u can help me fix that so i can submit this app?. thanks. please respond so i may go to sleep.

Comment: ok this seems to work but i cant say, because everywhere u put numberField i get an error and it says property numberField not found on object of type 'TipViewController'.

Comment: Thats because you need to change it to your own text field.

Comment: I can verify that the aforementioned code works on a `UITextField`. Id recommend trying to debug it on your own, if it still does not work and you run into another, specific issue then you may wan to open another question.

Comment: i will right now. incredibly, i had to remove that code because the dollar sign would not allow my tip calculator to calculate

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *price; 
NSString *dollarSign = "$";//Just use whatever currency symbol you need


price.text = [dollarSign stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", priceVariable]];
```

This will print  in the format $xxx.xx

Comment: That's not locale specific if someone uses another currency opens the app they're still going to see $.

Comment: @Antomir what happened when you used it? Did you get an error or anything. I just copied it from so code I'm currently using and it was working.

Comment: i got no error. it simply didnt work though. i think u are mistaken. my labels are fine. what is want is in my uitextfields. where u enter the bill total. Once the bill total is entered, i want the number that u entered to be in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `UITextField` subclass to handle currency formatting, available here:

https://github.com/TomSwift/TSCurrencyTextField

It formats the currency amount as the user types, ATM-style.  The user is restricted from entering anything but digits.  The control uses a NSNumberFormatter (currency-style!) internally and you can tweak that if you like, to adjust the currency symbol ($), decimal places, etc.